# add an resize logo inside picture using Js or framework

Tags: javascript

please is there any js framework or code that will let me resize an uploaded logo inside an picture,
like this example on picture
A :image to resize
B : tool to use
Thanks
i cane't upload image 
the link below at vk

https://vk.com/id181761990?z=photo181761990_456239019%2Fphotos181761990

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQueryUI to create the [slider for 1-100% size](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#custom-handle), and [on slider change value](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change), resize the image pointing at it with an unique id.
I'd use an empty div with two backgrounds (shirt and image on it) to easily keep the image always in the middle of the shirt without using text aligns and calculated values.

Comment: thanks but i don't now how, pls is there any tutorial

Comment: Not for what you are asking for. You need javascript, css, jQuery and jQueryUI fundamentals to understand what to do. Even with a working example, without them you probably won't understand how it works and Stack Overflow is about learning, not about get free codes :)

Comment: Okey thanks, i'm using Vuejs for fronend items, i'm not that fun of jQuery but thanks u gave me an idea